# Can you determine the volume of this pyramid?

Tags: geometry

A coworker posted this image on the whiteboard today:

[image]

And the quote is "Can you determine the volume of this pyramid?" Now, I've been able to determine the following:

[image]

And ∠BDC is a right angle. However, its apparently been so long since geometry class that I can't figure this out. Is this actually solvable?

**EDIT**

The person who wrote it just informed me that is is a 3 sided base, not 4.

Comment: How tall is it?

Comment: I put in the question all the info given.

Comment: Unsolvable question because of insufficient info.

Comment: @Mick That's my question. Is this actually able to be solved? He claims it can be.

Comment: I don't think so unless he means that the pyramid is in the form of a regular tetrahedron with each edge is of length = x.

Comment: @Mick: It is...

Answer (score 0):

If it a regular tetrahedron with each edge is of length = x, then

1) the base is an equilateral triangle of sides all equal to x. Its area can therefore be found.

2) it height can also be found because the vertex is vertically above the centroid of base triangle.

With the above facts, its volume can then be found in terms of x.

By the way, your friend has drawn a misleading diagram. It should be a 3D one.